# Connection string not getting detected in ADO.NET Entities

Tags: vb.net, wcf, ado.net, database-connection

I for the first time tried the ADO.Net Data entity model and would like to work wiht linq on it.  I did my entity connection and following code to test connection:

```
Public Function SaveContact(ByVal ContactValue As Contact, ByVal IsNew As Boolean) As String Implements IContactService.SaveContact
    Dim db As New salessolEntities
    db.Database.Connection.Open()
    db.Database.Connection.Close()
    Return Nothing
End Function
```

However, I am getting the following error:

> No connection string named 'salessolEntities' could be found in the
>   application config file.

The connection string is correctly set in app.config:
Default version(auto generated):

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="SalesSolWcfLib.My.MySettings.DBConnection" connectionString="server=localhost;User Id=root;password=surpavan;database=salessol;Persist Security Info=True;Old Guids=True" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
    <add name="salessolEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=localhost;user id=root;password=surpavan;database=salessol;persist security info=True;old guids=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

A small modifiction:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="SalesSolWcfLib.My.MySettings.DBConnection" connectionString="server=localhost;User Id=root;password=surpavan;database=salessol;Persist Security Info=True;Old Guids=True" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
    <add name="salessolEntities" connectionString="server=localhost;User Id=root;password=surpavan;database=salessol;Persist Security Info=True;Old Guids=True" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Another modification:

```
<connectionStrings>

        <add name="SalesSolWcfLib.My.MySettings.DBConnection" connectionString="server=localhost;User Id=root;password=surpavan;database=salessol;Persist Security Info=True;Old Guids=True" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
        <add name="SalesSolWcfLib.My.MySettings.salessolEntities" connectionString="server=localhost;User Id=root;password=surpavan;database=salessol;Persist Security Info=True;Old Guids=True" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
      </connectionStrings>
```

[image: Tables That got picked up]

Entire App.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="SalesSolWcfLib.My.MySettings.DBConnection" connectionString="server=localhost;User Id=root;password=surpavan;database=salessol;Persist Security Info=True;Old Guids=True" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
    <add name="SalesSolWcfLib.My.MySettings.salessolEntities" connectionString="server=localhost;User Id=root;password=surpavan;database=salessol;Persist Security Info=True;Old Guids=True" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
      </connectionStrings>
      <appSettings>
        <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
        <add key="ClientSettingsProvider.ServiceUri" value="" />
      </appSettings>
      <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" />
        <membership defaultProvider="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider">
          <providers>
            <add name="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientFormsAuthenticationMembershipProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" serviceUri="" />
          </providers>
        </membership>
        <roleManager defaultProvider="ClientRoleProvider" enabled="true">
          <providers>
            <add name="ClientRoleProvider" type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientRoleProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" serviceUri="" cacheTimeout="86400" />
          </providers>
        </roleManager>
      </system.web>
      <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
      app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
      <system.serviceModel>
        <services>
          <service name="SalesSolWcfLib.Service1">
            <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="SalesSolWcfLib.IService1">
              <identity>
                <dns value="localhost" />
              </identity>
            </endpoint>
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
            <host>
              <baseAddresses>
                <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/SalesSolWcfLib/Service1/" />
              </baseAddresses>
            </host>
          </service>
          <service name="SalesSolWcfLib.ContactService">
            <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="SalesSolWcfLib.IContactService">
              <identity>
                <dns value="localhost" />
              </identity>
            </endpoint>
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
            <host>
              <baseAddresses>
                <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/SalesSolWcfLib/ContactService/" />
              </baseAddresses>
            </host>
          </service>
        </services>
        <behaviors>
          <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior>
              <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
              set the values below to false before deployment -->
              <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" httpsGetEnabled="True" />
              <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
              set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
              to avoid disclosing exception information -->
              <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
            </behavior>
          </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
      </system.serviceModel>
      <entityFramework>
        <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
          <parameters>
            <parameter value="v11.0" />
          </parameters>
        </defaultConnectionFactory>
      </entityFramework>
    </configuration>
```

Please advise on which part I went wrong, this is a WCF project with Mysql.  My manual connection with "SalesSolWcfLib.My.MySettings.DBConnection" works well, but with ado.net I am facing this issue.  Please correct me where I went wrong.

Comment: I searched on internet for solutions, the only answer I see is that connection string is missing, however I have that in my app.config.

Comment: `SalesSolWcfLib.My.MySettings.salessolEntities` is not the same as `salessolEntities`

Comment: @DonA I tried the default and the my guesses, I have the original code and my tried code above as Modification.

Comment: The error says it cannot find a connection string named `salessolEntities`, do you see an element by that name?

Comment: Get rid of the other one so there is only one connection string and see if it works.

Comment: I edited my question, earlier the code did not get displayed due to wrong formatting, please check now.  Thank you.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, removed my one and kept the default one, no luck even then.

Comment: The `salessolEntities` has another overload for a connection string. You can use a `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder` and a `System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnectionStringBuilder` object to build it. That is how I separate testing and deployment.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41333/discussion-between-surpavan-and-dona)